# Are you able to use the Data Flows activity in a Managed VNet Synapse Workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, vnet

Is the Data Flows activity functional in a Managed VNet Synapse Workspace?

We have been unable to get any connections working, despite being able to use the Copy Data activity on those same Integrated Datasets.

When we attempt to pull data within a Data Flow, we always get a "Synapse Spark took too long to respond" error, which we're assuming has something to do with the Managed VNet aspect of the workspace.

Would love any help anyone can provide here!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this scenario is supported. If the problem persists, you should open an Azure ticket so that engineering can examine the logs to find the root cause for this error.